# Kafka-node client keeps sending request to broker which went down

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

When a broker host goes down/restarts, the kafka client keeps sending the new requests to the same hosts. As a result, the requests are failing with this error: Request timed out after 30000ms.

Node version: v6.8.1
Kafka-node version: 3.0.1
Kafka version: 2.11-2.0.0
Number of Brokers: 3
Number partitions for topic: 10

Some code pointers:

```
"clusterConfig" : {
  "kafkaHost": "localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094",
  "autoConnect": true
}
...
let kafkaClient = new kafka.KafkaClient(clusterConfig);
producer = new kafka.HighLevelProducer(kafkaClient, cluster.producerConfig);
Promise.promisifyAll(producer);
...
producer.sendAsync([eventPayload])
  .then(function (data) {
    let topicName = eventPayload.topic;
    let payLoadSize = (eventPayload || '').length;
    logger.eventInfo(topicName, payLoadSize, source);
  })
  .catch(function (e) {
    logger.produceFailedEvent(eventPayload, source);
    throw Error.getErrorObject(errorType, e, topic, source);
  });
```

I have the kept the other configurations to default.
Please help in resolving the issue.

Thanks,
Shashank

Comment: When you say "broker host", do you mean "process"? Because if the host is down, then all the other localhost  connections would be down... Anyway, are you able to describe the topic after a broker is down? Does the topic actually have more than one replica?

Comment: @cricket_007 By broker host, I meant broker host ip address. I described the topic and the host which was down was not present among the leaders or isr. The issue seems to be on the kafka-node library side. My debug output which prints the hosts ip it is connecting: https://pastebin.com/LqMRxhuU

Comment: My point is that 3 brokers on one machine isn't really providing you any benefits unless each broker had a dedicated hard drive and cpu core for its processing. In fact, having 1 broker might even be more performant when dedicated to a single machine

Comment: @cricket_007 here the point / issue is not about performance. I am also facing same issue, 3 brokers and 3 zookeepers are for HA, consider them to be on different machine on production and on localhost for testing purpose. In between if one of the broker goes down , cluster still works, but library is not able to produce events intermittently and that's what is not expected behaviour of library. It should be able to handle broker bein unavailable in HA mode and still keep sending data to kafka.

Comment: @cricket_007 In production I have 3 different hosts, The code pointer was for local testing. I issue is present in both environments.

Comment: Have you tried a different Kafka library? In other words, I doubt this is actually a Kafka issue becaue the protocol should correctly handle leader-failover cc @mohit3081989

Comment: Obviously issue is not related to Kafka, it's with library. kafka-node is primary library for node and is actively maintained. Being of node, no other choice than this Kafka library.